# Query to restrict results from left join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query

```
select S.id, X.id, 15,15,1 from schema_1.tbl_2638 S
JOIN schema_1.tbl_2634_customid X on S.field_1=x.fullname
```

That returns the following results, where you can see the first column is duplicated on matches to the 2nd table.

```
1   1   15  15  1
2   3   15  15  1
2   2   15  15  1
3   5   15  15  1
3   4   15  15  1
```

I'm trying to get a query that would just give me a single row per 1st ID, and the min value from 2nd ID. So I want a result that would be:

```
1   1   15  15  1
2   2   15  15  1
3   4   15  15  1
```

I'm a little rust on my SQL skills, how would I write the query to provide the above result?

Comment: there is no left join and where is the second table and for that where is the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your result you can do,this to achieve your result, for much more compicated structures, you can always take a look at window fucntions

```
select S.id, MIN(X.id) x_id, 15,15,1 from schema_1.tbl_2638 S
JOIN schema_1.tbl_2634_customid X on S.field_1=x.fullname
GROUP BY 1,3,4,5
```

window function can be used, need always a outer SELECT

```
SELECT
    s_id,x_idm a,b,c
FROM
    (select S.id as s_id, X.id as x_id, 15 a ,15 b,1 c
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S.id ORDER BY X.id ASC) rn
    from schema_1.tbl_2638 S
    JOIN schema_1.tbl_2634_customid X on S.field_1=x.fullname)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Or as CTE

```
WITH CTE as (select S.id as s_id, X.id as x_id, 15 a ,15 b,1 c
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S.id ORDER BY X.id ASC) rn
    from schema_1.tbl_2638 S
    JOIN schema_1.tbl_2634_customid X on S.field_1=x.fullname)
SELECT s_id,x_id,a,b,c FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use the window function, but having a hard time finding the right syntax. Any suggestions?

Comment: it is basically always the same, i prefer the Group BY as it doesn't need another temporary table see my changed answer.